# MS Visual Studio 2013 MFC Application: Create a text box for messaging / output service

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, visual-studio-2012

Using MS VC, I've created a "Dialog based" MFC Application. Let's call it MyApp1. I simply want to add some kind of "box" to my dialog to display text. I tried to add an "Edit Control" and then printing to it via

```
var_set.SetCueBanner(_T("Test"), TRUE);
```

`var_set` is the variable of the Edit Control `CEdit`. This code is added in a function that is called when pressing a button in the dialog. E.g.

```
void MyApp1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
     var_set.SetCueBanner(_T("Test"), TRUE);
}
```

However, I think this is at least not the way an "Edit Control" should be used... So I tried with a "Static Text". To control it, I read to use

```
HWND hwndText = GetDlgItem(dlg, IDC_STATIC);
SetWindowText(hwndText, L"Test");
```

But I would have to use the ID of the dialog `dlg` which is not defined in MyApp1Dlg.cpp file. I found it in the MyApp1.cpp. Should I export that instance to MyApp1Dlg.cpp or is there another way to display text in my dialog? In the final application, I'd like to use it similar to a

```
printf("output: %g\n", xx);
```

command. Thanks for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SetCueBanner` function is for setting a *prompt* into the edit control. If you want to set the actual *text*, use [`SetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhczy8bz.aspx) - it's part of the parent class [`CWnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xb05f0h.aspx) so you would not find it in the `CEdit` documentation. This works for both edit and static controls, although a static control might also need a [`RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fdz8ey6.aspx) before it shows the new text.

```
var_set.SetWindowText(_T("Test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got an answer:
First, define an "Edit Control" box. Let's call the ID `IDC_EDIT1`. Next, in one of the MyApp1Dlg.cpp functions, insert

```
CString str;
str.Format(_T("%d x %d"), .5, .4);
SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, str);
```

and mark the property "Read only" to `True`.